# reading command line arguments through pipe to sh

Tags: linux, bash, shell, curl

I am running a shell script by piping it to `sh`.  For example:

```
curl commands.io/count-duplicate-lines-in-a-file | sh
```

The only way I could figure out how to pass in the filename was to use:

```
read file </dev/tty
```

You can check out the script here:
[Count duplicate lines in a file](https://commands.com/count-duplicate-lines-in-a-file)

Is there another way to pass in the filename as an argument to the script without first saving it to a file locally, setting permissions and running it?

The idea is you can use [Monitor](https://github.com/dtannen/monitor) to capture terminal input/output and then re-run it from the command line using `curl` piped to `sh`.

Comment: There are far better ways to do this

Comment: What is the significance of using `curl` rather than, say, `cat`?

Comment: commands.io/count-duplicate-lines-in-a-file is a resource on the web-- not on my local machine.

Answer (score 2):

Use `-s` option:

```
echo 'echo "$@"' | sh -s 1 2 3 4
```

Output:

```
1 2 3 4
```

Another way is to use process substitution if shell supports it:

```
bash <(echo 'echo "$@"') 1 2 3 4
```